# Hapi js - makemehapi Issue

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

Hi New Node and I am practising tutorial "makemehapi" In the third assignment I have receiving below error. Any one can point where I am doing wrong?

Regards,
Surya

------------ Code ---------------------

```
var Path = require('path');
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Inert = require('inert');
var server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({

    host: 'localhost',
    port: Number(process.argv[2]|| 8080)
});

server.register(require(Inert),function(err){

    if(err) throw err;


} )

server.route({

    method:'GET',
    path:"/index.html",
    handler: {

            file: "index.html"
    }

})


    server.start(function () {
      console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
    });
```

---------------------- error--------------------------

> ```
> assert.js:86
>   throw new assert.AssertionError({
>         ^
> AssertionError: path must be a string
>     at Module.require (module.js:364:3)
>     at require (module.js:384:17)`enter code here`
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/surya/Desktop/nodeschool/Hapi Practice/test/Lesson3.js:13:17)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
>     at startup (node.js:129:16)
>     at node.js:814:3
> ✗ Error connecting to http://localhost:18384: ECONNREFUSED
> events.js:85
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>             ^
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
>     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You are requiring in `Inert` twice. Remove the `require` around the `Inert` variable in the following line:

```
server.register(require(Inert),function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
});
```

To:

```
server.register(Inert,function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
});
```